# Open synced tabs automatically in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I'm running Firefox 15 on two Firefox synced Windows computers. Is there a way to have the synced tabs open automatically? The only way to access the tabs from the other computer is to manually open them from the history menu (something I forget to do all the time). I have heard about xmarks, but recent reviews mention a hanging issue.

Comment: You can type `about:sync-tabs` in awesomebar/address bar of FF and here you go, but its manual. :P

Answer (score 3):

The best option for your case would be to use [Xmarks](http://blog.xmarks.com/).

> Well, Xmarks tries to reduce this headache and keeps your bookmarks
>   online and can sync your bookmarks whereever you are, as it is an
>   online bookmark tool. No need of exporting and importing bookmarks.
>   All you have to do is install Xmarks and sync your profile. This works
>   for Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

Navigate to [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/) and install the addon Xmarks-sync on Firefox.

### Enable Open Tab

Manage your Open Tab settings:

- Open Xmarks settings(`Firefox` > `Tools` > `Xmarks` > `Xmarks Settings` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>).
- Now Under Xmarks Settings Dialogue box click on Sync Tab and check `Open Tabs`:
  [image]
- Enter a name for your computer into the text field:
  [image]
- Click **OK** to save your settings and exit.

### How to Sync Open Tabs

On Remote Computer access: `Firefox` > `Tools` > `Xmarks` > `Open Remote Tabs` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, but one would think that with the built-in Sync that there might be a way for Firefox to do it without the added weight of an add-in.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround, which isn't automatic but at least reminds you to open the tabs of the other device is this:

In Preferences, General, set the Behaviour to "Show my home page" and the Home Page to `about:sync-tabs`, like this:
[image]

Now, when you start Firefox, it'll present you with a list of tabs from the other device(s), you can select all of them and right-click "Open selected Tabs" (maybe click "Refresh" beforehand).